# Pythonic way to map enum to api values

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-3.7

I have a proto generated code which has 3 values (values i am interested in)

```py
proto_type.VALUE1
proto_type.VALUE2
proto_type.VALUE3
```

I have created an enum in my python project.

```py
class MyEnum(Enum):
    VALUE1 = 0
    VALUE2 = 1
    VALUE3 = 2
```

The sole reason i have done this so that i can restrict callee to use specific values. Now I want to map `MyEnum` to `proto_type` values.

I was thinking to create a dictionary i.e.,

```py
Mapping = {
  MyEnum.Value1: imported_proto_type.VALUE1,
  MyEnum.Value2: imported_proto_type.VALUE2,
  MyEnum.Value3: imported_proto_type.VALUE3,
}
```

What i wanted to ask is this best pythonic way to do so? Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dictionary for mapping is very common and easy to understand practice. Now there is another way to handle this without mapping. If the values in `proto_type` are integers that following way would be better.

```
from enum import IntEnum

class MyEnum(IntEnum):
    VALUE1 = proto_type.VALUE1
    VALUE2 = proto_type.VALUE2
    VALUE3 = proto_type.VALUE3
```

Now you can use this as follow.
`MyEnum.VALUE1.value`

Comment: @EmAe: You don't actually need the `.value`, as `MyEnum.VALUE1` will be equal to whatever `proto_type.VALUE1` is.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the proto generated values in your Enum?

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
  VALUE1 = imported_proto_type.VALUE1
  VALUE2 = imported_proto_type.VALUE2
  VALUE3 = imported_proto_type.VALUE3
```

Then if you have:

```
x = MyEnum.VALUE1
```

You can get at the proto value directly by writing:

```
x.value
```